# How to load an external Angular app inside a div?

Tags: javascript, angular, single-page-application

I need to create a single-page-application calendar web app which acts as a widget, so clients can plug it on their websites inside a specified div container. How can I achieve this?

Would Angular be a suitable framework for this task?

Comment: At the end of the day Angular compiles down to Html and JS, it doesn't matter what you use to build it. Clients will include a simple script that loads the external html into the specified div

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```html
HTML:

  <div [innerHtml]="KisshtHtml"></div>

Ts:

name = 'Kissht';
  KisshtHtml: any;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient,
  private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){

  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.http.get('https://razorpay-dbf86.web.app/',{responseType:'text'}).subscribe(res=>{
      this.KisshtHtml = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(res);
    })
  }
```